# Ajax.request using ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm having difficulty loading JSON content from a file. `console.log` prints `"server-side failure with status code 0"`, meaning that the request failed.

My JSON file URL is correct and the file is present at the given address.

Firebug shows the error:

```
"NetworkError: 405 Not Allowed - http://localhost:8080/4910.json?_dc=1336714070619
```

and the Net tag shows status `405 not allowed`.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                   url: 'http://localhost:8080/4910.json',
                   success: function(response, opts) {
                      var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                      console.log(obj[0].name);
                   },
                   failure: function(response, opts) {
                      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                   }
                });
```

Also, what is adding the parameter `_dc=1336714070619` to the end of the GET request?

Answer (score 7):

Just FYI..

For the **Who is adding parameter _dc**. dc stands for **disable cache**.
by default, every request in extjs will automatically append the request variable with **_dc**. more [info](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-property-disableCaching)

If you don't want it, just set `disableCaching: false` to your request

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    disableCaching: false,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/4910.json',
    ......
});
```

For the **why not allowed**.
Try opening the JSON URL path without `_dc`, or maybe there is something wrong with your server.

Answer (score 3):

if the file you accessing is in the same domain, you can directly give the relative path there.

**if the request is cross-domain:**
If you need to read data from another domain and can't set up a proxy server (some software that runs on your own domain's web server and transparently forwards requests to domainB.com, making it look like they actually came from domainA.com), you can use Ext.data.proxy.JsonP and a technique known as JSON-P (JSON with Padding), which can help you get around the problem so long as the server on domainB.com is set up to support JSON-P responses. See JsonPProxy's introduction docs for more details.

**Check** http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the relative path for the `url` (relative here is comparing to the js file), for example it should be `4910.json` if the json file is at the same folder as your js file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, wrong server port?

This works good for me:

```
Ext.Ajax.request ({
    url: 'http://localhost:80/sof/json.json' ,
    disableCaching: false ,
    success: function (res) {
        // JSON is {name:val, type:val}
        console.log (Ext.JSON.decode(res.responseText).name);
    } ,
    failure: function () {
        console.log ('error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check about your webserver settings. My MAMP on OSX has localhost:8888.

Every time I use a file on localhost I use relative paths.

Have you tried to change the file permissions with CHMOD? Maybe you can't even open it in your browser?

Have you tried to write to the file from within php and checked afterwards?