# Using ExtJS4 + PHP with RESTful web services

Tags: php, rest, model-view-controller, extjs4

I want to build an app using ExtJS 4 and PHP.

I will follow the MVC pattern with ExtJS 4.
However, I want to use RESTful webservices with PHP.

Yet I am not sure how to proceed.

How can I call for Web Services that are PHP functions? 
How am I going to give the directory like structure to my links?

Comment: With regards to the php web service, i'd recommend checking out [this tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/). Uses the slim framework for creating restful services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obviously use `Ext.Ajax.request()` to craft any RESTful URls that you want. However, be sure to check out the REST proxy that's built into Ext JS's data package. By connecting this to your store/model, you can dynamically generate RESTful URLs which can be used for the vast majority of your generic CRUD operations.

RE: the PHP side, that's a big question. Fortunately, there are literally a billion turtorials on creating RESTful services in PHP, so I'd dust off your Google-fu and start there. Here's a very simple introduction that just happens to use PHP: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/ajax.html).

There are some examples of Ext.Ajax.request from this [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545961/ajax-request-using-extjs).

Comment: Maybe I don't follow your question. You will have a PHP script and use that as the url for your ajax request.